# SWIFT - cornerRadius is not working in custom CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

Im trying to get rounded UICollection cell but i found out that it's not working somehow and I can't come up why. I have a TableView in regular ViewController, in this tableview i've a custom table cell (in specified section) and in this custom table cell I've a CollectionView also with custom collectionCell and if i do anything rounded there, it's just not rounding anything. I cliped testBtn into bounds, but it wasn't work with this... I also tried testBtn.layer.masksToBounds with no success. However, if I'am doing a rounding in parent (tableView cell itself), it's working just good...

CollectionViewCell code:

```
import UIKit

class ProfileTileCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var testBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var contView: UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        testBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        testBtn.clipsToBounds = true
        // Initialization code
    }

    @IBAction func testClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        print("clicked")
    }
}
```

Screenshot of the mainView: [Screenshot.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyUKH.jpg)

Blue color is a background of collectionView, gray is background of cell and violet is a button. I don't know if it's getting late but it's weird for me, not be able to get working this thing... I'm missing something... Any help I will appreciate !

Comment: Your code looks fine. Maybe show a screen shot of the view hierarchy for your cell. Also, just to make sure, in your storyboard (or xib), did you set the cell class name to ProfileTileCollectionViewCell in the identity inspector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a great 8 hours of sleep and cuz that and Rob's comment, I tried to dig into debug for a bit, and I noticed a warning message which were saying that behaviour of UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not set... (and so on). So I decided to set up UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout like this:

```
extension ProfileTilesTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top:0, left:10, bottom:0, right: 10)
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.width - 40) / 3 , height: collectionView.frame.height - 5)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10
}
```

And finally :D somehow it started working properly !

So I deleted everything that I used for testing, deleted testBtn and changed testBtn.roundedCorners to contView.roundedCorners, set back the collectionView properties and it's looking near to what I'm looking for: [Screenshot2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaZk0.jpg)

Thanx for your answers, especially to Rob's one. This is what I was looking for !

Best regards SB !

Answer (score 0):

Try to set testBtn.layer.masksToBounds = true

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, I guess you have added corner radius in your collection view and set clipsToBounds true. If you don't need rounded collection view then remove cornerRadius and set clipsToBounds false. Or if you need both of them rounded then maintain padding between collection view and button. You can do this by fine-tuning the section inset property.